# Equation of a line in complex form

Tags: complex-numbers

The question is to find out the equation of two lines making an angle $45°$ with a given line $\bar{a} z+a\bar{z} +b=0$ (where $a$ is a complex number and $b$ is real) and passing through a given point $c$ is ($c$ is a complex number)

---

Writing $z$ as $x+iy$ we get the slope of the given line as $\frac{-Re(a)}{Im(a)}$ I then tried to get the slope of the line which makes angle $45°$ with given line but unable to proceed further.Any ideas?Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It may help to think of these lines as vectors. They add and subtract just like vectors and they have scalar and vector products as well. For example, given two complex lines, say $z_1$ and $z_2$, then the complex product $z_1z_2^*$, where * denotes the conjugate gives both the scalar and vector products. Specifically,

$$\Re\{z_1z_2^*\}=|z_1| \cdot |z_2| \cos(\zeta)=\frac{1}{2} (z_1z_2^*+z_1^*z_2) \\
\Im\{z_1z_2^*\}=|z_1| \cdot |z_2| \sin(\zeta)=\frac{1}{2} (z_1z_2^*-z_1^*z_2)$$

where $\zeta$ is angle between the two vectors.

This may help you to get the angle between two lines.