# Let $z_1, z_2 ∈ C$. Show that $Re (z_1, z_2)$ is the dot product in $R^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let z<sub>1</sub>, z<sub>2</sub> ∈ C. Show that Re(z<sub>1</sub>z<sub>2</sub>) is the dot product in $R^2$, how would you approach this? Im taking my first curse in complex analysis and I got stuck early it seems

Comment: Show us what you've tried. I assume you wrote $z_1=x_1+iy_1$, etc.

Comment: You may find the answer in a previous question that I answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2273727/equation-of-a-line-in-complex-form/2273745#2273745