# Complex number can't be cross multiplied!

Tags: complex-numbers, vectors

The question below confused me:
[image]

I think what confused me is that he asks to perform a x b i.e. cross product. However, Cross/vector product can be applied to VECTORS only and NOT to complex numbers where "j" is NOT the wye coordinate vector it's just the imaginary notation.
I mean if he asked
a x b
or a.b
they're both the same.
Am I right?

Comment: I think they just want you to multiply the two complex numbers, not cross multiply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) only applies to vectors in three dimensions, so this is asking you to multiply normally.

However, you can think of complex numbers as vectors on the complex (Argand) [plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product). So you can take the dot product equivalent of two complex numbers.

Comment: Ok, what I meant is that when dealing with complex numbers there is no such a thing as cross product. so, a x b = a.b Right

Comment: What you say is not correct. There are both scalar and vector product equivalents for complex numbers. See my previous answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2273727/equation-of-a-line-in-complex-form/2273745#2273745.

Answer (score 0):

As others have indicated, **half** of the problem is performing the multiplication.  The other **half** is as follows:

Suppose that $z = x + iy$, and you are required to express this as 
$re^{i\theta} = r[\cos \theta + i\sin\theta].$

Then $r = |z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}~$ and, (assuming that $|z| \neq 0$) within a modulus of $(2\pi)$, 
$\theta$ is **completely** determined by:

$\cos(\theta) = \frac{x}{|z|},~~\sin(\theta) = \frac{y}{|z|}.$

Comment: You're overcomplicating this: $ab = 20$.

Comment: @TobyMak Yes and No.  I didn't notice that result is $\in \mathbb{R^+}$, which certainly means that $\theta \equiv 0\pmod{2\pi}.$  On the other hand, it is probably a good idea to give the OP a general algorithm for converting $(e + if)(g + ih)$ into polar coordinates.