# Can we do the same type of operation in vectors like we do in complex numbers and vice-versa?

Tags: complex-numbers, vectors

We know that e^itheta in complex numbers is very special because it makes the complex numbers to rotate some angle about origin . Is there a similar thing present in vectors too which rotate a vector by some angle? And what about the cross product in vectors , can we be able to find a complex number which is perpendicular to plane formed by some two complex numbers and the origin?

Comment: For the scalar and vector product in complex variables, see my previous answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2273727/equation-of-a-line-in-complex-form/2273745#2273745.

Comment: Really nice thanks @CyeWaldman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operation  $z \to e^{i \alpha}z$ has a close equivalent in 3D.

Indeed, the rotation with angle $\theta$ about **unit** vector $V_0:= \begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c \end{pmatrix}$ is

$$R_{\theta,V_0}=\exp(\theta [V_0]_{\times})\tag{1}$$

where $\exp(M)=I+M+\frac12 M^2+ \frac{1}{3!} M^3+\cdots$ is the **matrix** exponential and $[V_0]_X$ is the antisymmetric matrix defined by

$$[V_0]_{\times}=\begin{pmatrix}0&-c&b\\c&0&-a\\-b&a&0\end{pmatrix}\tag{2}$$

Important remark: One could define $[V_0]_{\times}$ by the following formula :

$$[V_0]_{\times}V=V_0 \times V\tag{2}$$

In detail:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&-c&b\\c&0&-a\\-b&a&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-cy+bz\\ \ \ cx-az\\-bx+ay \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: And what about the cross product relation to complex numbers Sir ? This i understood for rotation what about perpedicular to the plane complex number finding ?

Comment: The common relationship is with respect to orthogonality ($\perp$) relationship. Operation "multiplying by $i$" the number $a+bi$ gives $-b+ai$ with $(-b,a) \perp (a,b)$ is completely similar to operation "taking the cross product gives a vector that is $\perp$ to the initial vector.

Comment: See the Edit I just added.

Comment: Very nice understood fully Sir thanks

Answer (score 1):

The quaternions may be used in place of complex numbers to describe three dimensional rotations. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation).

Let $\vec{u}$ be a unit vector (the rotation axis) and consider the quaternion $q = \cos \frac{\alpha}{2} + \vec{u} \sin \frac{\alpha}{2}$. Then
$$\vec{v'} = q \vec{v} q^{-1} = \left( \cos \frac{\alpha}{2} + \vec{u} \sin \frac{\alpha}{2} \right) \, \vec{v} \, \left( \cos \frac{\alpha}{2} - \vec{u} \sin \frac{\alpha}{2} \right)$$
yields the vector $\vec{v}$ rotated by an angle $\alpha$ around the axis $\vec{u}$.

Comment: Thanks Sir i understood it