# Angle between two complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Consider a complex function $f(z)=(z-(1+i))^3$ and $z_1(t)=1+it$, $z_2(t)=t+it$, $t \in [0,2]$. Find the angle between $f(z_1(t))$ and $f(z_2(t))$ at $z=1+i$.

I did that $f'(z_1(t))=3(z_1-(1+i))^2z_1'(t)=3(1+it-1-i)^2 i=-i(t-1)^2$ and $f'(z_2(t))=3(z_2-(1+i))^2z_2'(t)=3(t+it-1-i)^2 (1+i)=3(t-1)^2(1+i)^3$. At $z=1+i$, $t=1$, and so $f'(z_1(t))=0$ and $f'(z_2(t))=0$ and so the angle between $f(z_1(t))$ and $f(z_2(t))$ is 0. Are my steps correct? Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need derivatives here? I'd just compute the two values, find their args, and subtract?

Comment: Is the answer 0? Should I put t=1 while finding the argument?

Comment: @BarryCarter consider a similar situation with differentiable $f,g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(y) = g(y)$ at some fixed real $y$. You can still ask what the angle between the functions $f,g$ is at $y$, even though they agree in value. Moreover, the angle will depend on derivatives of $f,g$ at $y$...

Comment: @gt6989b OK, I thought OP was looking for an angle between two complex numbers, but I might have read through too past.

Comment: @gt6989b Are my steps correct?

Comment: make sense to me

Comment: See a previous answer of mine here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2273727/equation-of-a-line-in-complex-form/2273745#2273745.